# Zend_Controller_Router_Route causing an 404 error

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

It's probably late and I have missed this off by a long shot.

I am trying to create a cleaner url structure; so rather than having

/index/about
/index/news

I have

/about
/news

I came across a post on this site which used the following:

```
public function _initCustomRoute()
{
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
    $route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(':action', array(
        'module'     => 'default',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action'     => 'index'
    ));
    $router->addRoute('default', $route);
}
```

It rewrites the url within my navigation. So I have created the relevant action and view (tested without the custom route) but I am getting:

> Not Found
>   The requested URL /path/to/public/index.php was not found on this server.

I assume this is a thing that apache does on a windows file system by not adding the drive letter.

I've not touched the .htaccess file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do requests to /index/news work? As that does not look like a ZF error, it looks like a problem with your rewrite setup

Comment: Tim, the problem was with apache and not the framework.  As in my answer, you have to create a virtual host to get this working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out why! You must use virtual hosts rather than an alias as I was using.

Full guide here: http://blog.ryantan.net/2010/03/setting-up-wamp-for-zend-framework-projects/